# Python: merging lists like this

Tags: python, list, merge

I have many troubles to merge two simple nested lists while keeping the overall structure. For example:

```
# From this source:

x = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]
y = [['A','B','C'],['D','E','F'],['G','H','I']]


# To this result:

z = [[['a','A'],['b','B'],['c','C']],
     [['d','D'],['e','E'],['f','F']],
     [['g','G'],['h','H'],['i','I']]]
```

Any idea?

---

Here, some (embarrassing) code I tried:

```
X = []
Y = []

for i in iter(x[:]):
    X.append('=')
    for v in iter(i[:]):
        X.append(v)
print X; print

for i in iter(y[:]):
    Y.append('=')
    for v in iter(i[:]):
        Y.append(v)
print Y; print


for i in zip(X, Y):
    print i
```

Comment: @AnttiHaapala No need to try anything. Someone will post a working solution soon enough.

Comment: @juanchopanza so it seems.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala This has definitely become a "write my code for me" site.

Comment: @Belen, If you add the code you tried it will stop people downvoting your question, even if you could not get  close to the solution as the answer is probably not overly obvious to a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print([list(map(list,zip(*t))) for t in zip(x,y)])
[[['a', 'A'], ['b', 'B'], ['c', 'C']], 
[['d', 'D'], ['e', 'E'], ['f', 'F']],
[['g', 'G'], ['h', 'H'], ['i', 'I']]]
```

The steps:

```
In [20]: zip(x,y) # zip the lists together
Out[20]: 
[(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['A', 'B', 'C']),
 (['d', 'e', 'f'], ['D', 'E', 'F']),
 (['g', 'h', 'i'], ['G', 'H', 'I'])]

In [21]: t  = (['a', 'b', 'c'], ['A', 'B', 'C']) # first "t"
In [22]: zip(*t) # transpose, row to columns, columns to rows
Out[22]: [('a', 'A'), ('b', 'B'), ('c', 'C')]

In [23]: list(map(list,zip(*t))) # convert inner tuples to lists
Out[23]: [['a', 'A'], ['b', 'B'], ['c', 'C']]
```